# Accessing data entered in a dialog box tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a simple GUI to enter a number using the button widget in python. I invoke a button which when pressed calls the a function named NumLibs. Numlib access the data from my call MyDialog. I wish to access the value stored in d.result in my main python program, but am unable to do so. Can someone help me access this value?
Please find my code attached.

```
**from Tkinter import *
import tkSimpleDialog
import sys
import os
import string
def callback():
    print "called the callback!"
class MyDialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):
    def body(self, master):
        Label(master, text="No.of Libraries :").grid(row=0)
        self.e1 = Entry(master)
        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        return self.e1 # initial focus
    def apply(self):
            first = string.atoi(self.e1.get())
        self.result=first
            #print first # or something

def NumLib():
    d=MyDialog(root)
    return d.result



root = Tk()
root.title("SIMKIT")
toolbar = Frame(root, width=300, height=300, bg="grey", bd=1, relief="sunken")
b = Button(toolbar, text="Enter No. of Libraries", command=NumLib)
b.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
toolbar.pack()
root.mainloop()**
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kaustubh

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Signatures are generally frowned upon. Please refer to the FAQ for more details.

Comment: Is the indentation broken in your code snippet? I am specifically curious about apply().

Answer (score 1):

You must set the result of the dialog box as an attribute of your main program instance. In this way you will have access to it.
For example, the following class reads the value entered and writes it in the button

```
class MyDialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):
    -----  same code ---------


class MyToolbar(Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kargs)
        self.b = Button(self, text="Enter No. of Libraries", command=self.NumLib)
        self.b.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.pack()

    def NumLib(self):
        d = MyDialog(root)
        self.result = d.result            # you have your value in this instance variable
        self.b.config(text= self.result)  # for example I can use it to change the button label


root = Tk()
root.title("SIMKIT")
toolbar = MyToolbar(root, width=300, height=300, bg="grey", bd=1, relief="sunken")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I wish to use the value stored in self.result in some other section of my code. I need this value for example say printed in after the instance of toolbar=Mytoolbar(...) in the main program. Is there a way of accessing the value of self.result ? Looking forward to your note.

Comment: When using GUI-based programs you usually run your main program inside the GUI. The code is normally situated in/called from inside your main frame. You only put code between GUI instantiation and the GUI Mainloop for initial configuration. So put/call the rest of your code in/from MyToolbar class and access the result from the dialog as I already did (using self.result).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `MyDialogresult` is only set in `apply()` - which may, or may not have been called when the button is pressed, and thus the variable `MyDialog.result` may not exist when `NumLib()` is called!

Try setting the value of `MyDialog.result` to some dummy value before the button is pressed, perhaps in a constructor or in the top-level of your class, and see what happens.